# RequestMapping on class with PathVariable

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, controller, interceptor, restful-architecture

I am developing restful webservices in spring mvc. All the requests coming from clients will include `/sessions/{token}` uri prefix in requestmapping. For example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(CardsController.URL_PREFIX)
public class CardsController{
    protected static final String URL_PREFIX = "/sessions/{token}/cards";
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value = "/get") 
    public @ResponseBody BaseResponse getCardList(){...}
    ...
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(AccountsController.URL_PREFIX)
public class AccountsController{
    protected static final String URL_PREFIX = "/sessions/{token}/accounts";
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value = "/get") 
    public @ResponseBody BaseResponse getAccountsList(){...}
    ...
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(BillsController.URL_PREFIX)
public class BillsController{
    protected static final String URL_PREFIX = "/sessions/{token}/bills";
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value = "/get") 
    public @ResponseBody BaseResponse getBillsList(){...}
    ...
}
```

I could make a base controller, and all these controller can extend this base controller. But how could i get {token} PathVariable value in every request and authenticate the user. If i send this token value in request header i can get it in interceptor and authenticate the user before controller. But i know that when i put this token information in uri, it must be authenticated in every function body and that is not good. Is there a precontroller mechanism other than interceptor that can handle the uri and do some job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't really be dealing with authentication in this layer, and authorization should be annotated. Spring security deals with this nicely, inserting A&A into the call chain before you ever hit your rest controller. Your rest controller should be concerned with application logic, processing commands, not security logic.